# Insert data into mySQL table, using POST and Server Request Method

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

I have a simple question, I hope I can finally do it .. I already created a database ("our_new_database"), I checked it in XAMPP, everything is fine, also I created credentials, a working connection, a HTML form and a table.

Now I have to insert information from the form (First Name, Second Name, Email) into the table, but first I must set 3 variables with NULL values and AFTER that to include them in IF/ELSE statement using `$_POST`.

The point is - user is entering information to the database, then his info is coming via `$_POST`request and inserting into the table. And this is where I can't proceed by myself, will be very happy if you help me.

This is the HTML Form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="userNameOne">User First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="userOne" id="userNameOne">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="userNameTwo">User Second Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="userTwo" id="userNameTwo">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="userEmail">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="email" name="userEmail" id="user_Email">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
```

This is the credentials + database connection + creating the table:

```
<?php

session_start();

$host = "localhost";
$user_name = "root";
$user_password = "";
$dbname = "our_new_database";

function db_connect($host, $user_name, $user_password, $dbname) {
    $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user_name, $user_password, $dbname);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");
    return $connection;
}

include "app".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."config.php";
include "app".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."db-connection.php";
include "app".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."form.php";

$foo_connection = db_connect($host, $user_name, $user_password, $dbname);

$sql = "CREATE TABLE user_info(
    user_name_one VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    user_name_two VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    user_email VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)";

if(mysqli_query($foo_connection, $sql)){
    echo "Table created successfully";
}
else {
    echo "Error creating table - table already exist.".mysqli_connect_error($foo_connection);
}
$foo_connection->close();
```

As I said, where I need to set up these NULL variables, and how to put them in IF/ELSE Statement, to get the `$_POST` request from the form and insert it into the table?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the users has submitted the form like this:

```
if ($_POST) {
    // user has submitted the form

    // get the form field values
    $userEmail = $_POST['userEmail'];
    // more fields...

    // validate the values

    // prepare the sql statements

    // execute insert statement here
}
```